# Differences between RLPx v3 and v4

Tags: devp2p, rlpx

I'm working on an implementation of a blockchain reader that will be operating in a limited environment; as such, I can't use any of the regular implementations. I'm running into issues with implementing devp2p, since the [current spec](https://github.com/ethereum/devp2p/blob/master/rlpx.md) only goes up to version 3, but the major clients all implement version 4. I've found documentation detailing the differences between v4 and v5, but nothing detailing the differences between v3 and v4. Does anyone know if these changes are available anywhere? I'd rather not have to reverse-engineer a cryptographic protocol from its implementations...

Answer (score 4):

Version 4 of RLPx was implemented under [EIP-8](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/b883968936d83aa1c458d48fdc81bc59e8095da5/EIPS/eip-8.md).

The implementations (and code changes) of which can be found in the following places:

- [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/pull/2091/files) p2p code
- Web3 [libp2p](https://github.com/ethereum/libweb3core/pull/46)
- [pydevp2p](https://github.com/ethereum/pydevp2p/pull/32/files)