# What (distributed) mechanism for broadcasting transactions and messages does Ethereum's P2P implement?

Tags: go-ethereum, network, architecture

> What (distributed) mechanism for broadcasting transactions and messages does Ethereum's P2P implement?

I know that each node on the Ethereum network is only connected to a (small) subset of the other network nodes.

So, how is the P2P broadcasting of transactions and messages implemented? - Is it by means of a gossip protocol (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gossip_protocol)?

Comment: Probably a dupe: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/12406/52